# Is $[0,\infty)$ a closed subset?

Tags: general-topology

A closed set is one where it contains all it's limit points, even though the end is 'open' as in the traditional sense any sequence tending to infinity will never leave the subset; therefore it's closed. Is my logic sound? Thanks!

Comment: You should specify if you mean "closed as a subset of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology". Is the complement of $[0,\infty)$ open in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, I mean as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.

Comment: @Matt The complement of $[0,\infty)$ is $(-\infty,0)$, right?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This set is indeed closed. Note that $+\infty$ is **not** a real number, sequences which tend to it are therefore non-convergent and have no limit in $\mathbb R$.

From this we can easily infer that $[0,\infty)$ is closed, since every sequence of positive numbers converging to a limit would have a non-negative limit which is in $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 8):

Note that the complement of $[0, \infty)$ is $(-\infty, 0)$, which is open in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore $[0, \infty)$ is closed.  I often find looking at the complement easier than thinking of limit points.

Comment: Why is $(-\inf, 0)$ open?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the topology: so $[0,\infty)$ is closed for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also: $[0,\infty)$ is a closed subset of $[0,\infty)$, regardless of the topology used.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are talking about $[0,\infty)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ in the natural topology? Then the answer is **yes**, this subset is closed.